# Powershell DSC: How to download and install MSI

Tags: powershell, dsc

Using Powershell DSC how do I download and install msi. I the references I have seen so far this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_farnhill/2015/03/15/using-dsc-to-download-from-azure-file-storage-to-an-azure-vm/. But I can only be used for shared folder no to http.

```
        File DownloadWebPi
        {
            DestinationPath = $PSScriptRoot
            Ensure ="Present"
            SourcePath = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287166"
            Type = "File"
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Script DownloadMsi
{
            GetScript = 
            {
                @{
                    GetScript = $GetScript
                    SetScript = $SetScript
                    TestScript = $TestScript
                    Result = ('True' -in (Test-Path c:\Somepath\install.msi))
                }
            }

            SetScript = 
            {
                Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287166" -OutFile "c:\Somepath\install.msi"
            }

            TestScript = 
            {
                $Status = ('True' -in (Test-Path c:\Somepath\install.msi))
                $Status -eq $True
            }
        }
```

And then next write next part to install msi which depends on this section.
Also don't use `$PSScriptRoot` as I believe this executes in system32.

Comment: thanks for the script could you please clarify on not using $PSScriptRoot what do you mean it executes in system32?

Comment: Do you use it in push or pull mode. I assumed pull mode. Either way you more likely should specify designated folder on machine or file server and use unc path for installation.

Comment: I am planning to use it as part of ARM scripts so that when VM is created it run the DSC script.

Comment: In that case you are running in push mode. Just push configuration to the server once. Also I've checked and $PSScriptRoot will most likely resolve to dsc module directory which isn't a best place to store msi's.